# Loggin in with Authlogic throws error I can't seem to debug. Any clues?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

```
Processing UserSessionsController#create (for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-10 01:45:03) [POST]
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Submit", "user_session"=>{"username"=>"iamtoc", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "action"=>"create", "authenticity_token"=>"t8W0rb/n2ew5hRZDCAy6FagbzgZPNXhWU5dwdOS9PnU=", "controller"=>"user_sessions"}
  [4;36;1mUser Columns (3.0ms)[0m   [0;1mSHOW FIELDS FROM `users`[0m
  [4;35;1mSQL (3.0ms)[0m   [0mSHOW TABLES[0m

NoMethodError (undefined method `where' for #<Class:0x5e42c98>):
  authlogic (3.0.3) lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/login.rb:122:in `find_with_case'
  authlogic (3.0.3) lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/login.rb:110:in `find_by_smart_case_login_field'
  authlogic (3.0.3) lib/authlogic/session/scopes.rb:95:in `send'
  authlogic (3.0.3) lib/authlogic/session/scopes.rb:95:in `search_for_record'
  authlogic (3.0.3) lib/authlogic/session/scopes.rb:94:in `send'
  authlogic (3.0.3) lib/authlogic/session/scopes.rb:94:in `search_for_record'
  authlogic (3.0.3) lib/authlogic/session/password.rb:183:in `validate_by_password'
  authlogic (3.0.3) lib/authlogic/session/callbacks.rb:83:in `validate'
  authlogic (3.0.3) lib/authlogic/session/validation.rb:64:in `valid?'
  app/controllers/user_sessions_controller.rb:9:in `create'
  C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
  C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
  C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
  C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
  C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
  C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
  C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
  C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
  C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
  C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
  /script\server:3
  C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:112:in `debug_load'
  C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:112:in `debug_program'
  C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/bin/rdebug-ide:87
  C:/Ruby187/bin/rdebug-ide:19:in `load'
  C:/Ruby187/bin/rdebug-ide:19

  [4;36;1mSQL (2.0ms)[0m   [0;1mSHOW TABLES[0m
Rendered rescues/_trace (51.0ms)
Rendered rescues/_request_and_response (1.0ms)
Rendering rescues/layout (internal_server_error)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to answer this question from this log. It seems like you use a newer(?) version of Authlogic than needed. (There is a missing function call)

Do you have some more version information?

Rails / activerecord version is required

```
Authlogic 3.0.3 depends on activerecord >= 3.0.7
```

You can install an older fix version of Authlogic if you need an older like this :

```
gem install -v <version>
```

Then if you use rails, you can specify the correct version to use. ( in environment.rb in case of 2.X) If you use Authlogic 3.0.3 I suggest you use Rails 3.

Comment: I installed authlogic 2.1.6 and uninstalled 3.0.3. And it worked perfect. I must say I'm blown away at the speed AND accuracy of your response!!!

Comment: @Stan Then accept kisp's answer please for some good karma all around.

Comment: I didn't even realize there was an option to accept answers. Thanks for bringing that to my attention.